# Proper declaration for generic BST extending another generic class?

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

What is the proper way to take a BST that contains a generic K and V and extend it to another class containing the same types K and V? What I have is:

```
public abstract class BST<K extends <Class<K,V>, V>
```

But this is incorrect because when I try to override the abstract methods by defining them in Class, I get an error message saying "the method [method-name] in the type BST is not applicable for the arguments (K)".

```
// Parent Class
public abstract class ParentClass<K,V> implements Iterable<K> {
    ...
}

// BST Class:
public abstract class BST<K,V> extends ParentClass<K,V> {
    abstract boolean containsKey(K k);
}

// Sub-class of BST Class
public class OtherClass<K,V> extends BST<K,V>{

 public boolean containsKey(K k) {
    if (this.key.equals(k)) {
        return true;
    } else return (left.containsKey(k) ||
            right.containsKey(k));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait a minute.  Do you want your *key* to be bound, your *value* to be bound, or *both*?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but I think I want just the key to be bound.

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  What hafizhan has is correct if you want to have your child class bound to the same generics as the parent class.  You mention a method; could you provide the signature of the method and the exact error message?

Comment: you were not override you method, the method signature is different, and also `public class OtherClass<K,V> extends BST` missing `<K,V>` at the end

Comment: Where is your `containsKey` method?

Comment: Oops sorry, I wrote it incorrectly here. But my actual code has the same method signature

Comment: oh ok that got rid of the error message! But now I get a type safety check warning for the containsKey method saying that it belongs to the raw type BST and that references to the generic type should be parameterized. Is there something else I need to parameterize? If I just ignore this warning, would it affect my code?